# Overflow:hidden effecting zoom image

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm creating a slider where `.slider-wrap` is a parent ***div*** which has rule `overflow: hidden;` and I want my every ***image*** should zoom in whenever I hover on ***div*** `slider-boxes` everything is working fine until I'm using `overflow: hidden;` but when I start to use `overflow: hidden;` image doesn't zoom out as the **Desired Result** in **Snippet 2** where I'm not using `overflow: hidden;`

I want my final result like **Snippet 2**

But I think **overflow** is important to use because there will be more images come when I will make it dynamic so is there any way to fix this issue.

here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rhulkashyap/7g3vypqh/

**Snippet 1: I'm Getting**

```css
body{
  background-color: #DD3735;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.slider-wrap{
  width:616px;
  height:120px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  margin:0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  border-radius:5px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
img, .slider-boxes{
  width:120px;
  height:120px;
}
.slider-boxes{
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.slider-boxes:hover{
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.30);
          transform: scale(1.30);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;  
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-wrap">
  <div class="slider-boxes"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000108340114/a586d7a8df39836a114651aef74cd2d0_400x400.jpeg" alt="Image1"></div>
  <div class="slider-boxes"><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/77/06/4e/77064e4e9ccc289ee5394dd7dbf48011.jpg" alt="Image2"></div>
  <div class="slider-boxes"><img src="http://gloimg.gearbest.com/gb/2014/201411/goods-img/1415993980392-P-2179386.jpg" alt="Image3"></div>
  <div class="slider-boxes"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000451012500/4628fbb9dc70514d389ed9491243866f_400x400.png" alt="Image4"></div>
  <div class="slider-boxes"><img src="http://howtodrawdat.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/1st-pic-Dave-Minion-from-despicable-me.png" alt="Image5"></div>  
</div>
```

**Snippet 2: Desired Result**

```css
body{
  background-color: #DD3735;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.slider-wrap{
  width:616px;
  height:120px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  margin:0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  border-radius:5px;  
}
img, .slider-boxes{
  width:120px;
  height:120px;
}
.slider-boxes{
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.slider-boxes:hover{
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.30);
          transform: scale(1.30);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;  
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-wrap">
  <div class="slider-boxes"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000108340114/a586d7a8df39836a114651aef74cd2d0_400x400.jpeg" alt="Image1"></div>
  <div class="slider-boxes"><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/77/06/4e/77064e4e9ccc289ee5394dd7dbf48011.jpg" alt="Image2"></div>
  <div class="slider-boxes"><img src="http://gloimg.gearbest.com/gb/2014/201411/goods-img/1415993980392-P-2179386.jpg" alt="Image3"></div>
  <div class="slider-boxes"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000451012500/4628fbb9dc70514d389ed9491243866f_400x400.png" alt="Image4"></div>
  <div class="slider-boxes"><img src="http://howtodrawdat.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/1st-pic-Dave-Minion-from-despicable-me.png" alt="Image5"></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Why `overflow:hidden` you required. every thing is working fine without that.

Comment: It is working with multiple images. https://jsfiddle.net/7g3vypqh/6/

Comment: `overflow:hidden` is important because when It will become dynamic then there will be  more then 10 or 15 images and could be more then that in a single line, that is why i want overflow because the parent div will have a specific width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the prettiest solution, but it does solve it somewhat..

Adding a

```
.sliding-wrap:hover
{
  overflow: visible;
}
```

does the trick, but it doesn't make the easing out very pretty..

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7g3vypqh/1/)